# MySQL takes 6 seconds for counting with conditions in 100k records

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
SELECT
  `id`, `code`, `description`, `minamt`
FROM `coupons`
WHERE
     `starts`<=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")
   AND
     `ends`>=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")
   and
      active=1
   and
      is_public=1
```

This mysql took 6 to 7 second to execute , because there are 100k records in coupons table

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coupons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bulk_coupon` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ctype` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Type',
  `code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n/a' COMMENT 'Code',
  `discount` float(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' COMMENT 'Discount',
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `minamt` float(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' COMMENT 'Min. amount',
  `custlogin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2' COMMENT 'Requires customer login',
  `freeshipping` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2' COMMENT 'Free shipping',
  `customer` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `products` text COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'Specific products',
  `categories` text COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'Spedific categories',
  `aod` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Apply on discounted products',
  `starts` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Start on',
  `ends` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Ends on',
  `is_public` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '2' COMMENT 'Active',
  `usage_type` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_used` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `cod_applicable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `return_policy` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `startEndDate` (`starts`,`ends`,`is_public`,`active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1201682 ;
```

Comment: You should provide tables structures `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` for every table involved in the question.. We also need to see the `EXPLAIN <query>` output. Those are the basic things required for a optimization question.

Comment: table structure updated

Comment: And the explain query? Besides MySQL version also might be needed `SHOW VERSION()`, MySQL versions have differences the optimizers.

Comment: mysql version is 5.5.56

Comment: EXPLAIN <query> output.?

Comment: Query Explain  : i need a records where  `starts` is greater  equal  then today and `ends` is less then today date
   and  active=1 and is_public=1

Comment: This is a assumption.. i assume the coupons are giving out daily in the past with x amount off days? What means `starts<=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")` can match a great number off records... The `starts<=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")
   AND
     `ends`>=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")` filter does not feel right here to be used on B tree indexes.

Comment: "Query Explain : i need a records where " With `EXPLAIN <query>` we mean [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) .. We want to know the Execution Plan Information

Comment: If you have many coupons that already finished and not too many that are in future, you should have better performance if you replace index (`starts`,`ends`,`is_public`,`active`) with index (`ends`,`starts`,`is_public`,`active`) or even with (`is_public`,`active`,`ends`). It depends on if you have many records where is_public != 1 and active != 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplification:

```
+------------+-------------------------------+
| CURDATE()  | DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d") |
+------------+-------------------------------+
| 2019-02-19 | 2019-02-19                    |
+------------+-------------------------------+
```

Indexes needed (Optimizer will pick one or the other):

```
INDEX(active, is_public, start)
INDEX(active, is_public, end)
```

Don't use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` for currency.  Use `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score -1):

A query rewrite might be.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    coupons.id 
  , coupons.code
  , coupons.description
  , coupons.minamt

FROM (

  SELECT
    coupons.id
  FROM coupons
  WHERE
       coupons.starts <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")
     and
        coupons.active=1
     and
       coupons.is_public=1  
) AS coupons_start
INNER JOIN 
 coupons 
ON
  coupons_start.id = coupons.id
AND
     coupons.starts <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")
   AND
     coupons.ends >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

This one seams to have a "better" exection plan that your query. 
Keep in mind executions plans on a empty table are not really sound. 
**So you need to do the EXPLAINS on your own MySQL also to verify**

```
EXPLAIN 

SELECT
  `id`, `code`, `description`, `minamt`
FROM `coupons`
WHERE
     `starts`<=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")
   AND
     `ends`>=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")
   and
      active=1
   and
      is_public=1

;

| id  | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref | rows | Extra       |
| --- | ----------- | ------- | ----- | ------------- | ------------ | ------- | --- | ---- | ----------- |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | coupons | range | startEndDate  | startEndDate | 3       |     | 1    | Using where |
```

Notice the `key_len` which is only 3 which means the query can only use a very small part of the `startEndDate` key

```
EXPLAIN 
    SELECT 
        coupons.id 
      , coupons.code
      , coupons.description
      , coupons.minamt

    FROM (

      SELECT
        coupons.id
      FROM coupons
      WHERE
           coupons.starts <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d") 
    ) AS coupons_start
    INNER JOIN 
     coupons 
    ON
      coupons_start.id = coupons.id
    AND
         coupons.starts <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")
       AND
         coupons.ends >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d")
       AND
         coupons.active = 1
       AND
         coupons.is_public = 1          

| id  | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref | rows | Extra                                               |
| --- | ----------- | ------- | ----- | ------------- | ------------ | ------- | --- | ---- | --------------------------------------------------- |
| 1   | PRIMARY     |         |       |               |              |         |     |      | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
| 2   | DERIVED     | coupons | index | startEndDate  | startEndDate | 10      |     | 1    | Using where; Using index                            |
```

Like i really said it's not really sound to get explains on empty tables. 
 Notice the `Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables` the optimizer know here the table is empty.
But also notice that the `key_len` is 10 and has the index type and using index which means the inner query can get the needed informations the id's to join from the index file alone..